# Is it better to ask about OSX server-related-questions (small-to.mid-sized, Enterprise) in Serverfault or Ask Different?

Tags: discussion, serverfault

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [How can I clear the DHCP GUI in OSX Server? Ghost clients in the building](https://serverfault.com/questions/773437/how-can-i-clear-the-dhcp-gui-in-osx-server-ghost-clients-in-the-building)

Answer (score 1):

I think you already asked the question!

OS X Server is topical enough here, but it [isn't considered as much of a serious server operating system](https://serverfault.com/a/49691/126632) as it was back in the days when Apple manufactured actual servers. So you might have to wait a while (or a very long while) before someone answers.

I have no idea what sort of reception this question would get on Ask Different.

Comment: Well, re: "I think you already asked the question," since I didn't previously have a serverfault account, I was only allowed to post on meta in regards to my own question.  Thanks for your info!  Will keep checking back.